# Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula. What does $\forall z\forall y((\phi(x)\land\phi(y))\to z=y)$ assert? ("Set Theory: A First Course" by Daniel Cunningham)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, predicate-logic

I am reading "Set Theory: A First Course" by Daniel Cunningham.

There is the following exercise in this book (Exercise 1.4.6 on p.23):

> Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula. What does $\forall z\forall y((\phi(x)\land\phi(y))\to z=y)$ assert?

My 1st answer is here:

> If $z\neq y$, then $\phi(x)$ or $\phi(y)$ doesn't hold.

My 2nd answer is here:

> $\phi(x)$ doesn't hold or if $z\neq y$, then $\phi(y)$ doesn't hold.

My 3rd answer is here:

> $\phi(x)$ doesn't hold or if $\phi(y)$ holds, then $z=y$.

Are my answers ok?

By the way, there is the following exercise in this book (Exercise 1.4.1 on p.23):

> What does the formula $\exists x\forall y(y\notin x)$ say in English?

I guess the correct answer is $x=\emptyset$.
Is the following answer ok or not? :

> There exists a set $x$ such that $y\notin x$ for all $y$.

Comment: 2nd correct: there is an empty set.

Comment: 1st one... we can rewrite it (see [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) as : $\phi(x) \to \forall z \forall y (\phi(y) \to z=y)$.

Comment: Thus, it read: either $\phi(x)$ does not hold or **for every** $y$ and $z$, if $\phi(y)$ holds, then $y=z$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much.

Comment: But if it applies to **all** values of $y$, then it applies also to $x$, meaning that if $\phi(x)$ holds, then $z=x$ for every $z$.